# EACCESS Permission error while creating react app in Mac OS X

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm getting the following warning while creating the react app, and after creating the project, I'm unable to add js file to the src folder I'm getting EACCESS in vscode

naseefali@NASEEFs-MacBook-Pro react % sudo create-react-app react-erp

Creating a new React app in /Users/naseefali/react/react-erp.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

> fsevents@1.2.13 install /Users/naseefali/react/react-erp/node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/fsevents
> node install.js

gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/naseefali/react/react-erp/node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/fsevents/build'
gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.4.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/naseefali/react/react-erp/node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v14.16.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok

> fsevents@1.2.13 install /Users/naseefali/react/react-erp/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fsevents
> node install.js

gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/naseefali/react/react-erp/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fsevents/build'
gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.4.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/naseefali/react/react-erp/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v14.16.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you just trying to run `create-react-app`? You probably don't need the sudo no? If you have node installed, you can just run `npx create-react-app my-app`